# How to use MoveWindow relative to other window?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, win32-process

I want to resize the window when other window has changed its size. Here is the scenario
[image]

Left side window is with index 0 and the right window with index 1. When left window is resized towards right then i need to resize the right window also. To do that I am using

```
if (tempIndex==0)
            {

                MoveWindow(handles[tempIndex+1], rct.Right + 1, rect[tempIndex+1].Bottom, rect[tempIndex+1].Right - rct.Left - 1, rect[tempIndex+1].Bottom-rct.Top,true);
            }
```

rct is a structure of type `RECT`. Where

```
private struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }
```

By using above code right window moves but it goes outside of screen and below the screen. I have very little knowledge about this.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Requirements aren't really clear.  Do you want the second window to stretch to fit the monitor? Is it always the same height as the first window?  Is it always the same width as the first window?

Comment: when a user stretches the left window towards right then i need to squeeze the left window proportionally towards right. Height will always be the same. But obviously the width of right window is going to be changed.

Comment: You may need to take into account the screen size and use Math.Max somehow to make sure you don't go off the screen.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx